# MySQL user and host precedence

Tags: mysql, privileges, sql-grant

I have two users, let's call them foo on two different databases:

Database_A:

```
mysql> select user,host from user where user = 'foo';
+-----------+-----------+
| user      | host      |
+-----------+-----------+
| foo | %         |
| foo | 10.%      |
| foo | localhost |
+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Database_B:

```
mysql> select user,host from user where user = 'foo';
+-----------+-----------+
| user      | host      |
+-----------+-----------+
| foo | %         |
| foo | 10.%      |
| foo | localhost |
+-----------+-----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now the issue I am running into is trying to run a SQL script w/ the DROP command. When I connect to the database on Database_A, I get an error trying to connect:

```
mysql -A -hdatabase_1.foo.bar.domain.com -ufoo -pbar Database_A <dbtables.sql
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1142 (42000) at line 22: DROP command denied to user 'foo'@'ip-10-128-0-143.ec2.internal' for table 'bar_table'
```

I can run this on the Database_B w/ no issues. So far, I have checked with the grants on both users and have logged into the MySQL shell w/ the same user and grants (foo@'10.%') but I can't run the SQL script on database_1. Here are what the grants look like for both Database_A and Database_B:

```
mysql> show grants for foo;
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@%                                                                                                                                                                         |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, RELOAD ON *.* TO 'foo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<redacted>' REQUIRE SSL                                                                  |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE ON `reference`.* TO 'foo'@'%' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for foo@'10.%';
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for foo@10.%                                                                                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT FILE ON *.* TO 'foo'@'10.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<redacted>' |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I can't seem to figure out why one database server would work vs the other one (both are set up exactly the same w/ the user and in the my.cnf). Is there a way where I can log in specifically as foo@'%'? I am trying to run this from a remote EC2 instance (same VPC):

```
mysql -A -hdatabase_1.foo.bar.domain.com -ufoo -pbar Database_A <dbtables.sql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't force connection as a particular user profile. MySQL uses the first matching profile, according to its sort order.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/connection-access.html:

> When multiple matches are possible, the server must determine which of
>   them to use. It resolves this issue as follows:
>
> - Whenever the server reads the user table into memory, it sorts the rows.
> - When a client attempts to connect, the server looks through the rows in sorted order.
> - The server uses the first row that matches the client host name and user name.
>
> The server uses sorting rules that order rows with the most-specific
>   Host values first. Literal host names and IP addresses are the most
>   specific. (The specificity of a literal IP address is not affected by
>   whether it has a netmask, so 198.51.100.13 and
>   198.51.100.0/255.255.255.0 are considered equally specific.) The pattern '%' means “any host” and is least specific. The empty string
>   '' also means “any host” but sorts after '%'. Rows with the same Host
>   value are ordered with the most-specific User values first (a blank
>   User value means “any user” and is least specific). For rows with
>   equally-specific Host and User values, the order is nondeterministic.

I would avoid giving different privileges to the same username, differing only by the hostname.

Even though MySQL allows you to define different privileges depending on the client host, it's confusing to manage your authorizations this way. I've never seen a good reason to do that.

If you need a distinct set of privileges, define a distinct username.

Comment: One last question, I have noticed between both servers that foo@'%' and foo@'10.%' are in different orders when i run a select on the mysql.user table. Does the output of these two have any direct correlation to the sort order that you mentioned? In other words, does it use the same Select to determine which user to connect as?

Comment: The order you get when you select is not the order MySQL uses. The docs say that literal host names and IP are most specific, and ordered first.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just adding the IP of the host im trying to run the command from with the necessary grants. Thanks so much for providing guidance on this.

Comment: Don't MySQL and MariaDB have both `'root'@'%'` and `'root'@'localhost'` enabled on the first default InitDB initialize? In addition, sorting results seems different in both projects (e.g. `SELECT CONCAT(user, '@', host, ' ', SUBSTRING(authentication_string, 1, 5), '... ', plugin) FROM mysql.user;`). Doesn't it affect the local authentication? For example, https://paste.gg/p/faither/b08cc71fd6954dacbba6157f4a993e6b (*Possible MySQL and MariaDB root user authentication priority*...). It requires more investigation of course, but couldn't do it right now due to some local circumstances.

Comment: The authentication plugin sorting may differ of course if compared with the above general select.

Comment: @Faither: `localhost` and `%` are different access methods. In MySQL and MariaDB, `localhost` uses only the unix domain socket, and `%` uses only TCP/IP. There's no ambiguity of which one to use for a given connection.

Comment: Roger that. Forgot it... Thank you very much, @BillKarwin!